# Overriden browser "encoding" setting causes invalid characters to be sent in POST data

Tags: unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I'm running into a frustrating problem that arises when the browser "encoding" setting is forced into something other than "Auto-Detect."  When my HTML form gets POSTed, characters such as "?" or "Â" are making their way into the database.  Is there a good way to deal with this?

Comment: Are you specifying a specific charset on your HTML form?  If not, you should be.  Otherwise, the browser has to decide which encoding to use, which can be based on the HTML's charset, the display charset, etc.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - I believe I am. I have a "Content-Type" meta tag that is "text/html; charset=utf-8". I have also tried an "accept-charset" attribute on the form tag. However, isn't all this overridden when someone chooses the "incorrect" setting in their browser?

Comment: you would have to ask the browser manufacturer.  That setting is supposed to apply when parsing the HTML, but who knows if it alos applied when posting data back to the server.  If the HTML says it wants a specific charset, that is the charset the server is expecting, so the browser should honor that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that at least on some browsers, `accept-charset` in the `form` tag specifies the encoding of the form data, in a manner that it immune to what the user might do with the settings. And this sounds very reasonable. The form data encoding may differ from the encoding of the page, and the attribute exists for this purpose.

Comment: This works on modern browsers other than IE. IE treats accept-charset as only a fallback for if the typed characters don't exist in the selected encoding, and not an override. For the case of UTF-8 you can try to trick IE into not using the selected encoding by putting a character in the form data that doesn't exist in any non-UTF encoding.